# 'Invalid Toolchain' error while submitting iOS 9 compatible app

Tags: ios, iphone, submission, toolchain

I already googled about this error and noticed I'm not the only one whose getting this one during app submission, but I'm asking this question anyway because mine was the special case:

Many who are getting 'Invalid Toolchain' error are using OSX El Capitan or Xcode GM version. I'm not currently using any of beta software from Apple. I formatted my mac and installed fresh new OSX Yosemite & Xcode from Mac appstore few days ago. The project I was trying to build & submit was generated months ago, but suddenly I get the error in iTunesconnect while submitting the app and don't see what is wrong about my work.

Is submitting apps compatible with iOS 9 forbidden by Apple for some reason? Anyone who gets the error with official release of OSX & Xcode, please help me through with this.

Thanks.